# The condition of $\vec x \mathbf A=\vec 0$ when the $\mathbf A$ is a matrix,which elements are all generated randomly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to ask that the condition of $\vec x \mathbf A=\vec 0$,and i have some thinking ,i hope that someone can tell me if my thinking is right or wrong.

First,$\vec x \mathbf A=\vec 0$,$\vec x$ is still not a null space vector of $\mathbf A$,because the definition of null space vector should be  $ \mathbf A \vec x = \vec 0$,not $\vec x \mathbf A=\vec 0$.So the condition doesn't have any relation with Rank–nullity theorem.

Assume $\mathbf A$ is a $C\times R$ matrix ,so the $\vec x$ should be $1 \times C$ vector,now if the elements in the $\mathbf A$ are all generated randomly,and there are C unknown elements(variables) in the $\vec x$,and i want to know the elements in the $\vec x$.So i have to assume $C > R$,or the this system is  underdetermined Systems in most of case.

And $\vec x \mathbf A=\vec 0$ ,i can say that $\vec x$ is orthogonal to the $\mathbf A$,but i can't say  $\vec x$ is $Null(\mathbf A)$,and neither say that $\vec x$ is a vector which is projected onto the $Null(\mathbf A)$

Comment: $\vec x^T$ is a null space vector of $\mathbf A^T$, though.

Comment: @Arthur Thx for your information,so $\vec x$ is "not" the null space vector of $\mathbf A $ right?

Comment: Well, for one, $\vec x$ seems to be a _row vector_. Usually, when talking about null spaces, you're talking about spaces of column vectors. That being said, you can transpose everything, and you will be in a more familiar framework.

Comment: But you can apply the rank-nullity theorem to get information in your situation.  Use the method of @Arthur.

Comment: Question needs information.  "Generated randomly" where?  In some finite field?  In the complex numbers (if so, with what probability measure)?  They are generated randomly, but are they assumed to be independent?

Comment: you  can seem generated randomly as generated independently